# Would globally aliasing the fork bomb prevent its execution?

Tags: bash, security, alias

If you were to globally set

```
alias ':(){ :|:& };:'='echo fork bomb averted'
```

would that be an effective security strategy to avoid the Bash fork bomb execution or would there still be a way to execute it?

I suppose the question cashes out to: is there a way to execute a command when it's aliased to something else?

Comment: Could someone elaborate on what a fork bomb is and why we're protecting against it?

Comment: @user1717828, a "fork bomb" is a program that simply runs new copies of itself, forever.  The resulting exponential growth in the number of programs running usually causes something to break in short order.

Comment: Even if this did work -  it wouldn't protect against a program that calls fork() not going through bash?

Comment: :(){:|:&:|:&};:

Comment: Just run `a(){ a|a& };a`

Comment: You'd avoid the common form (if you'd get it to work at all), but there's a near infinite amount of variations on it possible.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The <strike>two</strike>, no, <strike>three</strike>, ... Amongst the  main obstacles to that are:

1. It's not a valid name for an alias. [Bash's online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

   > The characters ... and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

   `(`, `)`, `&`, `|` and whitespace are out in Bash 4.4.
2. That particular string is not the only way to write a fork bomb in the shell, just famous because it looks obscure. For example, there's no need to call the function `:` instead of something actually composed of letters.
3. If you could set the alias, the user could unset the alias, circumvent it by escaping the alias name on the command line, or disable aliases altogether, possibly by running the function in a script (Bash doesn't expand aliases in noninteractive shells).
4. Even if the shell is restricted enough to stop all versions of a fork bomb, a general purpose system will have other programmable utilities that can recurse and fork off subprocesses. Got Perl or a C compiler? Easy enough. Even awk could probably do it. Even if you don't have those installed, you'll also need to stop the user from bringing in compiled binaries from outside the system, or running `/bin/sh` which probably needs to be a fully operational shell for the rest of the system to function.

Just use [`ulimit -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-ulimit) (i.e. `RLIMIT_NPROC`) or equivalent to restrict the number of processes a user can start. On most Linux systems there's [`pam_limits`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_limits.8.html) that can set the process count limit before any commands chosen by the user are started.

Something like this in `/etc/security/limits.conf` would put a hard limit of 50 processes to all users:

```
*        hard    nproc           50
```

<sub>(Stephen Kitt [already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465306/170373) point 1, Jeff Schaller [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465307/170373) 2 and 3.)</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to write a fork bomb without `&`?

Comment: @StephenKitt I am not 100% sure but my guess is that bash is turing complete. If so there are likely infinite possibilities. For example you could parse ascii char-code 38 and execute it.

Comment: @Marie in this particular context you’d also have to avoid any of the other forbidden characters while working around the `&` limitation.

Comment: My point was mainly that trying to blacklist bad functionality is a bad idea. There are almost always ways around.

Comment: @StephenKitt, Would just `x() { x|x; }` work? It should recurse and multiply exponentially too, it just runs in the bottom level and not all levels at the same time like the background version would (I suppose). And yeah, `eval "$(printf "somecmd \044")"`.

Comment: @ilkkachu neither of those are valid alias names ;-)

Comment: @Marie point taken, security by blacklisting is indeed rather futile.

Comment: @StephenKitt, yeah, you can't use an alias to cover over something like that, and even if you could, there'd be an unlimited number of alternative ways to write the same.

Comment: @Marie: Bash is quite certainly Turing complete.

Answer (score 17):

**No. There are just too many ways to write a fork-bomb.**

The evil fork-bomb writer will just try again with a different function name. Or other alterations until his fork-bomb succeeds.

The inadvertent fork-bomb writer won't produce the canonical fork-bomb in the first place.

It's actually rather easy to become an inadvertent fork-bomb writer yourself. For instance, you could just use recursive `make` with an external, unchecked `cd`, combining it with the `-j` option and non-existing subdirectories -- a real example I've stumbled upon once.

**You cannot safeguard against all possibilities, and most certainly not against a determined attacker.** All you will achieve is to increase the complexity of your system.

Answer (score 14):

You can’t alias a fork bomb, because it’s not a [valid alias name](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases):

```
$ alias ':(){ :|:& };:'='echo fork bomb averted'
bash: alias: `:(){ :|:& };:': invalid alias name
```

> The characters ‘/’, ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘=’ and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

Some shells don’t check alias names when they’re declared, but when interpreting commands, and skip the invalid name then. A fork bomb will always include `&`, which can’t be included in a valid alias name, so protecting yourself in this way isn’t possible.

Comment: Whether a shell permits to set up this alias or not does not matter. Important is that even iff such an alias exists, it is not expanded while interpreting commands since the alias name does not match the permitted pattern. `dash` and `bosh` e.g. both silently ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

Twice, no.

That's not the only way to write a fork-bomb.

There's also several ways to execute "a command" when there's an alias:

```
command the-command
\the-command
```

Example:

```
$ alias ls=not-really-ls
$ ls
-bash: not-really-ls: command not found
$ \ls
jeff.html  output.png
$ command ls
jeff.html  output.png
```

Comment: Not related to main topic but why did `\ls` show `output.png` but `command ls` didn't?

Comment: Well-spotted! That is, indeed, unrelated to the main topic. It's a classic [PEBCAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#Acronyms_and_other_names) error where I copy/mis-pasted (or cleaned up the output.png in-between). I'll fix it to minimize distractions. Thank you, @nxnev!